# Android/Java. Как задать (увеличить) отступ иконки Navigation Drawer'a от края?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-navigation-drawer, icon

Как задать (увеличить) отступ иконки Navigation Drawer'a от края?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а какой у вас ActionBar - Sherlok, AppCompat?

Comment: Я подозреваю, что AppCompat

Comment: Да, вроде компакт. Ну точно не Sherlock...

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю если человек использует Navigation Drawer, то там используется

```
"android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar"
```

Тогда если вы хотите сделать отступ, используйте такой пример:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
```

где `android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"` и есть отступ от левого края на 15dp.